# Vite + Vue3 new project - Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have just created a new Vite + Vue3 project using npm init vue@latest.

On loading the project in VSCode, I get the following error in Main.ts, when importing App.vue:

```
Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations
```

The app seems to work fine, so I assume this is an issue with my VSCode config. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I resolved this by enabling Volar's takeover mode, a more performant alternative to the older extension option. Follow these steps:

1. Open the command palette (ctrl+shift+p in Windows)
2. Type 'Extensions: Show Built-in Extensions'
3. Search for 'TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features' in the extensions tab that has appeared
4. Select 'Disable (workspace)' (click on the arrow to the right of the 'Disable' button)
5. Open the command palette again and enter 'Developer: Reload Window'

Comment: Works for me, too. I also had to disable Vetur, in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the issue for me.

Using:
- Vue 3.2.47
- Vite 4.2.0
- Vitest 0.29.3

I get the error in my test-files: `HelloWorld.spec.ts`

`Cannot find module '@/components/HelloWorld.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

I have added a `paths` attribute to my `tsconfig.json` but it seems as if it doesn't help:

```json
"paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src"]
    }
```

Comment: @waldemar_enns, you need to add something like `"src/**/*.vue"` to your `tsconfig.json` `include` array.